# Integral over circular disk region to Integral over rectangular region.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I was going through the double integral over the general region in the plane and had a question.

When we integrate over a circular disk :
$$
D=\{(x, y) \mid \delta(x) \leq y \leq \gamma(x), a \leq x \leq b\}
$$
We do,
$$
\int_a^b \int_{\delta(x)}^{\gamma(x)} f(x, y) d y d x
$$
I would like to integrate over the semi circular disk defined by, $\gamma(x)=\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}$ and $\delta(x)=0$.
Instead of this if I wanted to make my work easier and instead of dealing with a case where the elementary region is a circle or semi-circle, I want to make it a rectangle.

Because I need the same volume, I would need the base area to be equal at every height, which essentially boils down to making the base area the same. As in both cases, the base area won't decrease as a function of height.(i)

So, now let's make the area equal.

$\operatorname{Radius}(r)=\frac{|b-a|}{2}$

Area of the circular disk $=$ Area of the rectangle.
$$
[D=\{(x, y) \mid d \leq y \leq c, a \leq x \leq b\}
$$
$$
\frac{\pi|b-a|^2}{4}=|b-a| \times l
$$

$l=\frac{\pi|b-a|}{4}$

$l$ is $|d-c|$

I can make $c=0$, and that would mean $d=\frac{\pi|b-a|}{4}$
Now, I do
$$
\int_{\mathrm{a}}^{\frac{\mathrm{a+b}}{2}} \int_0^{\frac{\pi|b-a|}{4}} f(x, y) d y d x
$$
We do $\frac{a+b}{2}$ because I want to find the volume which has the elementary region as a semi-circle, so I should make the rectangle's area equal to the semi-circle which we can do by halving the length of the rectangle. (ii)

My question is what is the conceptually wrong thing I am doing here? There must be some conceptual gap that I am not seeing. Are the statements in (i) and (ii) wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After some help from my friends, looks like the problem was with statement (i). Unless $f(x,y)$ is a constant, we cannot be sure that the volumes under the surface would be the same even if the base area is the same. If $A$ represented the rectangular region and $B$ represented the circular region, apart from $A\cap B$, other regions such as $A-B$ and $B-A$, don't necessarily have their volumes equal to each other as each point in that region may have different functional value from each other.

Below is an image for a visual aspect of the above comment.
[image: The volume given by the rectangular elementary region which has the same area as the circular elementary region.]